# PHP, Return everything to the left, strrchr()?

Tags: php

The following code returns everything to right of the last occurrence of a dash:

```
$string1 = 'some-random-string-123456';
$string2 = strrchr($string1, '-');

echo $string2;

output: -123456
```

is there a function that will return everything to the left of the last dash? so the out put would be:

```
some-random-string
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$string2 = substr($string1, 0, strrpos($string1, "-"))
```

Comment: Removed my answer as this is slightly more elegant.  +1

Answer (score -2):

Something like this will work..

```
$string2 = substr($string1, 0, strpos($string1, '-'));
```

Comment: This outputs "some", not what was asked